# Read data from Avro files using Flink 1.2

Tags: java, apache-flink

I have been trying to figure out how to read data from Avro files using Flink 1.2.0 (it has to be this particular version) for several hours now and I have only found contradictory information.

For starters, Flink's [documentation](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.2/dev/batch/connectors.html#avro-support-in-flink) mentions that we should use an *AvroInputFormat* but this class is nowhere to be found (at least it is not included in the maven dependencies: flink-java, flink-streaming-java_2.10, and flink-clients_2.10).

Am I missing something?

My concrete question would be: was Avro support removed in version 1.2.0 and the documentation is just outdated?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `AvroInputFormat` is located in the `flink-avro_2.10` dependency.

There are no plans to drop Avro support.

Comment: Thanks. Given that flink-avro is not an inherited dependency of any of the other libraries I suggest mentioning in the documentation that this dependency should be included.

Comment: The documentation is part of the official flink repository. If you are interested, feel free to contribute this to our documentation :)

Comment: I updated the documentation but according to the guidelines there has to be a JIRA ticket describing the change. Could you create that so I can submit the pull request?

Comment: I think the Apache JIRA allows everybody (with an account) to create a JIRA ticket.
(Let me know if you don't want to create an account for just creating the JIRA. I don't want to torture you.)

Comment: Done. The pull request is here https://github.com/apache/flink/pull/3638